# How to change the contents of the modal through javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am making Quiz module. In which student can take quiz. once submitted, if the quiz is not passed, than students can 'retake quiz'. Once students click on 'retake quiz', only questions for which user gave wrong answer will be showed up. I am using php and HTML modal for showing the questions for the first time when student take quiz. Than using jquery and javascript, I am passing the responses of user to backend and checking if it is passed or failed. If failed, than I have wrong questions id, whihc I want to display when they take 'requiz'. Following a code:

**Index.php**

```
//When user clicks this button, modal will be pop-up and questions will be displayed one by one.
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Quiz" id="start-quiz">Start Quiz</a>


<!-- Quiz Modal -->
<div class="modal fade quiz-modal" id="Quiz">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <? foreach ($questions as $i=>$question) { ?>
            <div class='question'>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4>QUIZ</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="quest-content" class="quest">
                            <h4 class="question-title"><?=$question->number?>) <?=$question->title?></h4>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <? foreach ($question->getAnswers() as $answer) { ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="<?=$answer->title?>">
                                                <?=$answer->title?> 
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <? } ?> 
                            </ul>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <p class='error'>Please select an answer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p class='quest_num'><?=$question->number?> of <?=count($questions)?></p>
                    <?  if( count($questions) === 1 ) { ?>
                        <a class="btn button btn-lg quiz-btn">Submit Quiz</a>
                    <? } else if ( count($questions) === $i +1 ) { ?>
                        <a class="btn button btn-lg quiz-btn">Submit Quiz</a>
                    <? }  else { ?>
                        <a href="" class=" btn button btn-lg quiz-btn">Next Question</a>
                    <? } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is `<script>` where I am doing couple of things: if there are more questions, button will show 'Next' and if it's a last question- button will show 'Submit'. Once submit the quiz, it will send user's responses to backend through `$.post` and get back the array of questions IDs that were wrong. Using this wrong question's ids, when user clicks on 'Retake Quiz', it should  show quiz again with these ids only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    var answers = [];
    $('.quiz-btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var checkbox = $(this).parents('.question').children('.modal-body').children('.row').children('.quest').children('ul').children('li').children('.checkbox').children('.icheckbox_square');
        var btn = $(this).parents('.question').children('.modal-footer').children('.quiz-btn')
        var next = false
        var submit = false
        console.log(checkbox)
        $(checkbox).each(function(){
            if ( $(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Next Question' ) {
                answers.push($(this).children('.cb:checked').val());
                console.log(answers);
                next = true
            } 
            else if ($(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Submit Quiz') {
                answers.push($(this).children('.cb:checked').val());
                submit = true
            }
        });

        if ( next ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('.question').slideUp(500);
            $(this).parents('.question').next('.question').delay(500).slideDown(500);
        } else if ( submit ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post('/student/submit_quiz',{answers: answers, module: <?=$model->course_module->id?>}, function(data){
                var correct = data['correct'];
                var incorrect = data['incorrect'];

                if(incorrect){
                    if(incorrect.length > 0){
                        var div = $('.quest')[$('.quest').length - 1];
                        var footer = $('.modal-footer')[$('.modal-footer').length - 1];
                        var progress = (correct.length*100)/(<?=count($questions)?>);
                        div.innerHTML = "<h4 class='question-title'>" + (correct.length)+"/<?=count($questions)?> questions correct <h4>";
                        div.innerHTML += "<div class='error'><p><strong>We are sorry but you have " + incorrect.length +" answers incorrect</strong><br>Please go back and review and reanswer those questions.</p></div>";
                        footer.innerHTML = "<a onclick='retakeQuiz(["+incorrect+"])' class='btn btn-success btn-lg quiz-btn'>Retake Quiz</a>";
                    } else {
                        var div = $('.quest')[$('.quest').length - 1];
                        var footer = $('.modal-footer')[$('.modal-footer').length - 1];
                        var progress = (correct.length*100)/(<?=count($questions)?>);
                        div.innerHTML = "<h4 class='question-title'> Congratulations!! You Passed this Module.<h4>";
                        footer.innerHTML = "<a href='/student/course/<?=$model->course->id?>' class='btn btn-default btn-lg'>Continue</a>";
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(next)
            $('.quest .error').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});

function retakeQuiz(incorrect) {
    $.each(incorrect, function(key, val) {
        alert('index ' + key + ' points to file ' + val);
        //Here incorrect is the array of Wrong Question's IDs. How can I use that id to show only this questions in my above modal. 
    });
}
</script>
```

I would like to know you all that I have only one Modal- that shows the quiz questions one after another and when quiz is completed and user submit the quiz, it will show the message of pass or fail along with the respective button say 'Continue' or 'Retake Quiz'. If 'Retake Quiz' is clicked, wrong questions will be displayed on the modal. So I have only one modal, but just changing the contents  dynamically through javascript.

I tried my best to explain my question and code. Hope to get some help. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: At the beginning of the quiz, how you are getting questions to display? I mean through directly by php or by Ajax call?

Comment: In the beginning, its directly by PHP

Comment: In your question `$question->number` is question id?

Comment: No it's a display order number of question. The questions id can be `$question->id`

Answer (score 0):

Doing manipulating from two sides like this always ends up in a bit of a tizy. Instead of changing the questions by using jQuery, can you change your PHP endpoint to return modal content given a set of ids? Here is the big idea:

Your PHP code has an endpoint that takes in a list of ids. These ids get passed off to the PHP code which does it thing and returns a list of questions of the ids (and corresponding answers). When a user first visits your page, your PHP code auto-loads all of the questions into the modal so the user gets the entire quiz (similarly to how you are loading on initial page load now).

Once they finish the quiz, you said you stored the ids of the questions they got wrong. **What I would recommend is** sending the ids to your php code to return a newly generated modal only including the ids of questions they got wrong. Then, you can simply replace the modal content with the result. Something like this perhaps (this is all psuedo-code, but I hope it gets the idea across)

```
// user has finished taking the quiz

$.get({
    "url": "/yourendpoint" + ids.toString()
    "method": "GET"
}.then(function(data){
    $(".modal-content").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something like this, but am not sure how to do that. But surely will give it a try.

Comment: 1. Write PHP code that returns the questions
2. On your endpoint that returns the HTML page, call PHP code that returns questions and load it into your page like you have in the example above
3. Once the user has finished the quiz, request a different endpoint (you need to write this new endpoint) that returns the contents of the `modal-contents` with the questions injected in
4. Overwrite the HTML of `modal-content` like shown in the snippet. Hope this gives a bit more detail

Comment: Thanks. This gives me idea of how to do it. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add attribute **id** to the every question divison with the value of question id like below

```
<? foreach ($questions as $i=>$question) { ?>
        <div class='question' id="<? $question->id ?>">
          // Your remaining code here
        </div>
<? } ?>
```

After submitting the form, in your callback of ajax call, remove the question divs with the ids those are not present in the response like below

```
function retakeQuiz(incorrect) {
    // I am assuming incorrect as [id, id, id] for example
    $('.question').each(function (index, question) {
       if (!incorrect.includes($(question).attr('id'))) {
           $(question).remove();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Cool. I am trying it now. But how can I show the Questions with these change.?

Comment: You are dynamically constructing the questions html right? So if you click on retake quiz, what will happen? I am thinking it will take students back to the questions html. But If you try my suggestion, you won't see corrected questions now. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion and I am able to get the required output. But it's not visible on teh screen. When I debug and see that particular `<div>` which shows teh question, it shows correct output as required. But how to show the questions on screen.

Comment: @JohnCaverns  Let's consider, two divisions like, one for displaying questions and another for displaying **Continue** or **Retake Quiz** may be with score. So we have to hide the second(buttons div) and should display questions div again, if **Retake Quiz** has been clicked. While displaying questions div again you have to append the filtered questions again to the questions div.

Comment: @JohnCaverns  If possible, can you give me the JSON response of questions with answers from server, I'll make the fiddle here, that you can understand.

Comment: I followed your step. it worked now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @JohnCaverns if my suggestion helped you, I am very glad. Can you make the answer as accepted one and vote up?